# Exclude items based on subtype's property value in a fluent query over parent type

Tags: c#, mongodb, fluent

Let's say I have two classes: class A and class B that inherits from A. There's a Mongo collection of type A items, it contains items of that type and also of the type B (as class B inherits from class A). I construct predicates to be used with fluent query using `MongoDB.Driver v2.2.0`.

```
public class A
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
}

public class B : A
{
    public bool Show { get; set; }
}
```

There's a query that retrieves all of the items from that collection (of both types A and B) and the predicates are used to allow filtering on several properties of type A.

```
Expression<Func<A, bool>> predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<A>();

if (someCondition)
{
    predicate = predicate.And(x => x.Id = 123);
}

 FilterDefinitionBuild<A> filterBuilder = Builders<A>.Filter;
 FilterDefinition<A> filterDefinition = filterBuilder.Where(predicate);

 IFindFluent<A,A> fluentFind = aCollection.Find(filterDefinition); //aCollection is of type IMongoCollection<A>

var results = await retryPolicy
            .ExecuteAsync(() => fluentFind.ToListAsync())
            .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Recently, a need arose to exclude from results some of the items of type B based on a property that only exists in class B (so in items of type B). Solution seemed to be rather easy at first, just add the required condition to the predicate:

```
predicate = predicate.And(x => !(x is B) || !((B)x).Show);
```

However, after testing that out, it seemed that the query was translated improperly and I got a following error - `System.InvalidOperationException: Convert({document}).Show is not supported.`

In the end I had to settle up for an ugly way to do it:

```
filterDefinition = filterBuilder.And(filterDefinition,
                filterBuilder.Ne("show", true));
```

Is it possible to have that condition in a predicate in a way that actually works (and doesn't look like the last piece of code above)?